# How many times will $\{an+b\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ intersect in a range of $0 - R$

Tags: probability, number-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, intersection-theory

Given $2$ arithmetic progressions, $\{an+b\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and $\{cm+d\}_{m=0}^{\infty}$, where $a,c$ are distinct primes. These intersect any time there are integers $(n,m)$ such that $an+b=cm+d$, and after a single intersection $an_0+b=cm_0+d$ they will continue to intersect at $a(n_0+ct)+b=c(m_0+at)+d$ for every natural number $t$. The first intersection can be efficiently found using the extended Euclidean algorithm.

---

Now let's say we have $k$ such arithmetic progressions of the form $\{an+b\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ with distinct values of $a$, where $a$ is a prime and $0<=b<a$. Also it is given that $a\approx L$.

What is the number of intersections in a single point, we should expect to see in a range of $0-R$ where $R$ is a natural number?

Answering this question will help [my research](https://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=25901) on a new factoring method.

Comment: Are you looking for the number of nonnegative integers $\leqslant R$ that appear in all $k$ of the progressions, or those that appear in at least two of them? ("intersections in a single point" seems to indicate the former, but it's not clear)

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, "those that appear in at least two of them", tnx for asking.

Comment: That means using inclusion/exclusion. So what about the relative sizes of $k, L$, and $R$? If $R$ isn't *much* larger than $2^k$ and $L^2$, the approximation error will make an estimate useless.

Comment: @DanielFischer Good point! I think the more interesting case is when $R$ is bigger than $L^2$

Comment: It should be much larger. Assuming $L$ is also much larger than $k$ (otherwise we can't have $a \approx L$ for $k$ primes) the first rough estimate is $$\binom{k}{2} \cdot \frac{R}{L^2}$$ intersections, but the estimation error can be pretty large, so this estimate is only useful if $R$ is large and $k/L$ small.